# How to show all commits on all (local) branches using git log?

Tags: git

`git log --graph --oneline` only shows the current branch I am on.
But I'd like to see commits on other branches, which are not jet merged.

Answer (score 0):

use: `git log --graph --oneline --all` to show all accessible branches

```
* b546488 eee
| * 7f28b92 ddd
|/  
| * fd6b7b8 ccc
|/ 
* d656b93 bbb
* c9ee226 aaa
```

Comment: Technically, `--all` means *all references* (branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, `refs/stash`, and so on). If you just want branches, consider `--branches` instead. (But `--all` is my own default here.)